# zxing 1.6 ScanTest does not take me to the URL

Tags: zxing

I am using zxing 1.6 ScanTest to scan QR codes.  The functionality works to display the url  on the iphone screen but how do I get it to send the user to a web page based on the url in the QR code automatically?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

ScanTest is just a demo app. Its purpose is as an example for developers wanting to embed the ZXWidgetController in their own code.

You could look at the Barcodes app in the SVN repo. It's supposed to be more complete and there was some effort made recently to clean it up and modernize it.